# Levenshtein in PHP

Tags: php, codeigniter, model, foreach, levenshtein-distance

I have written these function in a model (I am using CodeIgniter).

```
    function getLocalIngrdname()
{
    $this->load->database();
    $query = $this->db->get('onl_local_ingrd');
    foreach($query->result() as $row)
        $allingrd[]=$row->ingrd_localname;
    return $allingrd;
}

    function getCloseIngrdname($ingrdname,$localname)
{
    $this->load->database();
    $query = $this->db->get('onl_ingrd');
    foreach($query->result() as $row)
        $allingrd[]=$row->ingrd_name;

    foreach($localname as $row)
        $allingrd[]=$row;

            $shortest=-1;
            foreach ($allingrd as $ingrd) {
        $lev = levenshtein($ingrdname, $ingrd);
        if ($lev <= $shortest || $shortest < 0) {
            $closeword  = $ingrd;
            $shortest = $lev;

        }
    }
        return $closeword;
   }
```

This function is in controller

```
   function getResult()
   {
    $this->load->model('searchRecipe_model');
    $ingrdname = $this->input->post('ingrdname');
    $output[]=2;
    $localnames[]=$this->searchRecipe_model->getLocalIngrdname();
    $output[]=$this->searchRecipe_model->getCloseIngrdname($ingrdname,$localnames);
    echo json_encode($localnames); 
  }
```

`$allingrd` is an array of ingredient names. I display the `$closeword` in javascript alert message.
If I give`$lev=levenshtein($ingrdname,$allingrd[0])` it works perfectly; however, it's not working in the loop. Any ideas as to why? Thanks in advance.

Comment: `levenshtein()` wants both params as strings. Also, *not working* how?

Comment: What is happening when you run it in a loop? What do you expect to happen? You'll need to provide more context.

Comment: what is in the array `allingrd`?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you have som strings which are longer than 255 chars? The levenshtein() function returns -1 in those cases, which means the last such string will always be "the shortest" according to your algorithm. If this is your problem, you'll need to discard values where $lev equals -1 in this way:

```
foreach ($allingrd as $ingrd) {
        $lev = levenshtein($ingrdname, $ingrd);
        if (($lev <= $shortest || $shortest < 0) && $lev != -1) {
            $closeword  = $ingrd;
            $shortest = $lev;

        }
}
return $closeword;
```

Note that $closeword may not always be set (if, for example, all strings in $allingrd is longer than 255 chars, or if $allingrd is empty). Don't forget to initialise $closeword to something sensible before the loop, for example false, null or an empty string.

Answer (score 0):

I think that what you're trying to do is:

```
foreach ($allingrd as $ingrd) {
        $lev = levenshtein($ingrdname, $ingrd);
        if ($lev <= $shortest || $shortest < 0) {
            $closeword[] = $ingrd;
            $shortest[] = $lev;

        }
}
return $closeword;
```

Now $closeword is an array. You were just redeclaring the value of $closeword, for each time your loop was running. Now, you will throw the values inside an array. Same for $shortest.

Answer (score 0):

Notice how on PHP's [levenshtein](http://php.net/manual/en/function.levenshtein.php) page they declare `$shortest` as `-1`.  This is pretty important or else you'll never meet the requirements of the `if` statement.

```
$shortest = -1;
foreach ($allingrd as $ingrd) {
        $lev = levenshtein($ingrdname, $ingrd);
        if ($lev <= $shortest || $shortest < 0) {
            $closeword  = $ingrd;
            $shortest = $lev;

        }
}
return $closeword;
```

This should do the trick.